# Make Android Studio apps available for all devices

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin

I have a question about Android Studio.
If I develop an app that I then upload to the Google Play Store, can I be sure that my Android Studio project runs well and looks good on all devices with an Android operating system?
So that the layout that I developed works well on all screen sizes? Will Android Studio do this for me on its own?
Or do you have to develop your XML layout for each individual smartphone with different screen sizes?

I would be very happy to hear from you.

best regards

Comment: See this : https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: `can I be sure that my Android Studio project runs well and looks good on all devices` it _really_ depends on your code. nothing we can really say here. `Will Android Studio do this for me on its own?` it's an IDE, depends on how you use it. `Or do you have to develop your XML layout for each individual smartphone with different screen sizes?`depends on your app, your code, a lot of things.

Comment: your question doesn't really have anything to do with android studio, because it's just the IDE you're going to be using to _code_ your apps, android studio won't do anything special really in that regard, so it depends on various other factors, like your code and what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

However, applications created in android studio will be able to fit all api's that you define in your gradle, it is recommended to test in the emulator from the initial api defined in the gradle, but in general it works well on several devices. The test is ideal to check if there will be no crash in some API's but the layout is usually positioned according to the screen of each device.
Good luck on your project.

Answer (score 0):

> So that the layout that I developed works well on all screen sizes

- For this, it depends on how you did your layout. Android has constraint layout which is the best to use

`ConstraintLayout is a layout on Android that gives you adaptable and flexible ways to create views for your apps. ConstraintLayout , which is now the default layout in Android Studio, gives you many ways to place objects. You can constrain them to their container, to each other or to guidelines.`

> Or do you have to develop your XML layout for each individual smartphone with different screen sizes

- For this, it will only base on your use case or if you have different UI design for phone and tablet devices, for example, you want your app to show a two-pane layout on a  larger screen (or a tablet), then you have to create a new xml for this. So you'll have `mylayout.xml` placed in layout folder (for phone device screen sizes) and `mylaout.xml` placed on layout-600sd600dp (for tablet device screen sizes).
- But if you only have on design for both phone and tablet devices, then you only need one xml layout.